# Using an inner class name and an object name same in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-classes

In the following code snippet, presumably it appears that it should issue some compilation error but it doesn't:

```
class Outer {
    public static class Inner {
        static String obj = "Inner";
    }

    static Optional Inner = new Optional();
    //The (inner) class name and the object name are same.
}

class Optional {
    String obj = "Optional";
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Outer.Inner.obj);
        //Refers to the string inside the optional class
    }
}
```

The class `Outer` has a static class inside it named `Inner`. Additionally, it declares an object (static) of the class `Optional` (`static Optional Inner = new Optional();`)

This object and the class names (inside the class `Outer`) are same which is `Inner`. The program displays `Optional`. The only expression `Outer.Inner.obj` within `main()` is expected to display `Inner` but it doesn't. The actual output is however `Optional` which is the case of the `Optional` class.

One way to display `Inner` is by changing the object name to something else.

```
static Optional Inner1 = new Optional();
```

From the output it displays, it appears that the object name (or a variable) is chosen over a type name (the class `Inner`) because they have the same name. What exact case is applied here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Paragraph 6.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2) of the Java Language Specification has some information about the rules that apply in this case.

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that **a variable will be chosen in preference to a type**, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that such a declaration is *obscured*.

This refers to paragraph [6.5 Determining the Meaning of a Name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5), which explains the rules in detail.

In your example, `Outer.Inner` could refer to the type of the nested class named `Inner`, or the static member variable `Inner`. The rules say the variable will be chosen over the type.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the class name is Outer$Inner.

Inner classes are essentially a hack introduced in Java 1.1. The JVM doesn't actually have any concept of an inner class, and so the compiler has to bodge it. The compiler generates *class* `B` "outside" of *class* `A`, but in the same *package*, and then adds *synthetic* *accessors/constructors* to it to allow `A` to get access to it.

Checkout the following post:

[Java inner class visibility puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086255/java-inner-class-visibility-puzzle)

Comment: It's indeed a very nice answer to a question which has not been asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the inner class has actually have its own .java file. 
That will make it clear to you why it chooses the variable over the Inner class.