# Object instantiation: Inner class and outer class with the same name (Java)

Tags: java, inner-classes

### Code description and ouput

In the following code. We have a class **TestInners**, one **inner class** A, one **method local inner class A** and one **outer class A**.

1. When we instantiate an object as in `new A().m();` the ouput is
   **middle**.
2. In order for the program to output **inner** we must instantiate the object after the  method local inner class A in the **go**method.
3. If we comment the inner class the program will output **outer**.

---

### Question

In the code as it is. Why did it output middle? Is there a preference for the inner classes first? then the outer classes? I got confused.

---

### Source code

```
   class A { void m() { System.out.println("outer"); } }
    
    public class TestInners {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new TestInners().go();
        }
        void go() {
            new A().m();
            class A { void m() { System.out.println("inner"); } }
            
        }
        class A { void m() { System.out.println("middle"); } }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you shadow symbols with more local definitions, [the more local one is chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931519/14955). This most frequently happens with method parameters vs instance fields, leading to the famous `this.name = name` idiom.

In your case, you can get to the outer class by using a fully qualified class name.

But don't name classes like that. Too much confusion for no reason.

Comment: Or said another way: Only ever do that if you're deliberately trying to [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) the code.

Comment: I would even say "avoid having classes of the same name even across entirely different packages". Something like `java.util.List`, `java.awt.List`, `com.mypackage.List` only messes up auto-completion and makes things harder to read (have to dig out the imports to see what is being used). I think we got a couple of questions caused by List/List  (or Data/sql.Date) here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you point the JVM spec as well on the same for inner classes ?

Comment: And don't even think about naming classes the same as stuff in `java.lang`.  `com.mypackage.String` :-(

Comment: @javaguy JVM spec on *what*?

Comment: @javaguy: For language spec on name resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931146/using-an-inner-class-name-and-an-object-name-same-in-java?rq=1

Comment: on shadowing behavior

Comment: @javaguy JVM has nothing to do with name shadowing. The JLS (Java Language Specification) will however define such rules. If you open the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) and **search** for `shadow`, you'll very quickly find relevant specs (§6.4). This is called *research*, and is a very valuable technique all programmers should learn.